# Alert if last closed candle is x larger than the average of y previous candles

Tags: pine-script

How can I implement a function which alerts me if the latest closed candle is x, say 30%, larger than the average of y, say 300, previous candles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ta.sma()` function to calculate the average.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

avg = ta.sma(close, 300)
large = close > (1.3 * avg)
alertcondition(large, "Large", "Large")
```

Comment: Beautiful when it's so simple you don't even need to test it!

Comment: I definitely didn't :D